# This query works on mysql but returns 0 on PHP (inverted order works though)

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query which works in MySQL Workbench but returns zero on Ajax call

```
(select `00E` from snai3 where `NomeSquadra` = 'GENOA - BRESCIA')
union
(select `1` from snai3 where `NomeSquadra` = 'GENOA - BRESCIA')
```

The funny thing is that this one inverted like this it works returning an array from both values

```
(select `1` from snai3 where `NomeSquadra` = 'GENOA - BRESCIA')
union
(select `00E` from snai3 where `NomeSquadra` = 'GENOA - BRESCIA')
```

The query is sent from an Ajax call as said above, I tried returning the SQL query from PHP to see if there were any changes made by PHP encoding or things like those (not much expert with PHP) and the query returned is identical.

Here is the PHP code for everyone wondering

```
$squadra = $_REQUEST["squadra"];
$tipo = $_REQUEST["tipo"];
$numero = $_REQUEST["numero"];
$array = array();
$tipo = str_replace(".","",$tipo);
$tipo = str_replace(" ","",$tipo);

$sql = $squadra;
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0 && $result->num_rows == $numero) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        array_push($array,$row[$tipo]);


    }
     $sisalValue = array_product($array);

} else {
   $sisalValue = 0 ;
}
```

[As you can see this works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4z01h.png)

[And this returns 0 while on server works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loy7T.png)

[In combo with others it works as long as it's not the first on the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1OU1.png)

Comment: You're sending SQL straight in from request parameter? Ever heard of SQL injection? Anyway I'd guess that `$sql` does not contain what you're expecting.

Comment: The site doesn't contain any sensible data and the user privileges is only capable of reading. Thanks for pointing out the SQL injection though! By the way, I tried outputting $sql value and it's the same query as described above (select `00E` from snai3 where `NomeSquadra` = 'GENOA - BRESCIA')union
(select `1` from snai3 where `NomeSquadra` = 'GENOA - BRESCIA')

Comment: An attacker can crash your server if you let them run an arbitrary SQL query, even if they have _no_ privileges.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for those useful infos, I'll look deep into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run a UNION query, the column name of the result is based on the *first* SELECT in the UNION.

In other words, in this query, the column name of the result is `00E`:

```
(select `00E` from snai3 where `NomeSquadra` = 'GENOA - BRESCIA')
union
(select `1` from snai3 where `NomeSquadra` = 'GENOA - BRESCIA')
```

Whereas in this query, the column name in the result is `1`:

```
(select `1` from snai3 where `NomeSquadra` = 'GENOA - BRESCIA')
union
(select `00E` from snai3 where `NomeSquadra` = 'GENOA - BRESCIA')
```

There are two solutions:

Use an alias to set the column name. You only need to do this in the first SELECT, because once the column names are set, subsequent unioned SELECTs cannot change them.

```
(select `00E` AS `1` from snai3 where `NomeSquadra` = 'GENOA - BRESCIA')
union
(select `1` AS `DOES NOT MATTER - THIS ALIAS WILL BE IGNORED ANYWAY` from snai3 where `NomeSquadra` = 'GENOA - BRESCIA')
```

An alternative is to fetch rows into a plain array indexed by ordinal position instead of by name. Then it doesn't matter what the column name is, you just reference it by its position. The first column in the result is in position 0.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    array_push($array,$row[0]);
}
```

Comment: Nothing short of a quality response Bill, keep up the good work.